# Excel if statement that calculates total hours and cost per employee

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I am trying to write an excel formula for calculating the total cost of employees hours for estimating a project schedule.

I have a column with Employees Hourly Rate (some making $100hr. some making 30hr) I also have a column with the number of hours worked per each employee.

I want a formula that will take the number of hours per employee, multiply it by the hourly rate for that employee and sum it for all emmployees.

Any help would be great!

Comment: maybe something with SUMIFS?

Comment: Please try attempting something next time and sharing it when you get stuck.  You literally said the answer yourself - multiply two numbers and then sum it.  We tend to expect a bit more effort be demonstrated in your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brad.  I'm new to the website so I don't have a full understanding of user expectations.  I can assure you that I attempted this on my own for awhile and looked up possible solutions via google and stackoverflow.  I was trying IF and Sum statements with no luck- I was unaware of the sumproduct function as I am a new Excel user. I apologize for inconveniencing you.

Comment: Coming back to reply is a great sign, keep putting in effort and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B:B)*(C:C))
```

where ColumnB is the hourly rate and ColumnC the number of hours (each person a different row).

Answer (score 0):

```
 |    A      |           B       |   C   |
 | EMPLOYEE  |EMPLOYEE-HOUR  RATE| HOURS |
 |-----------|-------------------|-------|
1| E1        | $110.00           |   40  |
 |-----------|-------------------|------ |
2| E2        | $130.00           |   25  |
 |-----------|----------------   |------ |
3| E3        | $210.00           |   10  |  
 |-----------|-------------------|-------|  
4| E4        | $90.00            |   70  |  
 |-----------|-------------------|-------|
```

You can have above spreadsheet and then can use formula as

```
= sumproduct(B1:B4,C1:C4)
TOTAL    $16,050.00
```